# Unable to install any firebase packages in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am using VisualStudio as an IDE.
On adding cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7 as a dependency and running pub get, I get the following error:

```
[firebase] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in firebase...                        
Because cloud_firestore >=0.13.4 depends on cloud_firestore_web ^0.1.1 which depends on firebase ^7.0.0, cloud_firestore >=0.13.4 requires firebase ^7.0.0.

So, because firebase depends on cloud_firestore ^0.13.7 and firebase is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because firebase depends on cloud_firestore ^0.13.7 and firebase is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1".
```

My "pubsec.yaml" file is as follows:

```yaml
name: firebase
description: A new Flutter project.
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you made any effort on trying to solve the issue yourself? Like going through similar issues of other users? If so please add it as part of your post.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase plugins are all versioned carefully for compatibility reasons, so if one of your version specs is off, it will break the dependencies. I also believe you are missing the `firebase_core` dependency.

Please run `flutter clean` and install the FlutterFire plugins with the exact commands given on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#add-flutterfire-plugins), and re-pull everything with `flutter pub upgrade`. There is additional information about the FlutterFire plugins [here](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebaseextended/flutterfire/) if you have additional issues.

Comment: I just did flutter clean, then added firebase_core: ^0.4.5 but I still get the same error. This line is common again "requires firebase ^7.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `firebase_core` before you can use any firebase packages inside your flutter app.

Please visit [this link](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core#-installing-tab-) to see the documentation.